# The markdown syntax on the on-topic page is not properly formatted

Tags: bug, on-topic-definition, offtopic, scope

The markdown syntax on the this page is not properly formatted: https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for bringing it up, I fixed it.